# printing a list in SML

Tags: sml, ml

I want to print a list inside a help function, for debugging purpose. And for some reason it's not printing anything. Does anyone know what's wrong?
Here is some of my code:

```
local
....
and xx(LparenToken) = "LparenToken"
| xx(RparenToken) = "RparenToken"
| xx(QuoteToken) = "QuoteToken"
| xx(DotToken) = "DotToken"
| xx(VectorToken) = "VectorToken"
| xx(IntToken(a)) = "IntToken"
| xx(CharToken(a)) = "CharToken"
| xx(StringToken(a)) = "StringToken"
| xx(SymbolToken(a)) = "SymbolToken"
| xx(BoolToken(a)) = "BoolToken"

and readList(nil) = []
| readList(lst:SchemeToken list) = (map(print)((map(xx)(lst))); read(getFirstSexpr(lst))::readList(getRestSexpr(lst)))
...
in
    some functions..
end
```

i have tried this also:

```
and readList(nil) = []
| readList(lst:SchemeToken list) = (print "x"; read(getFirstSexpr(lst))::readList(getRestSexpr(lst)))
```

it is not printing. i get just the answer:

```
- Reader.stringToSexpr "#(a b (1 2 3) c)";
val it =
  Vector
    [Symbol "a",Symbol "b",Pair (Number 1,Pair (Number 2,Number 3)),
     Symbol "c"] : Sexpr
```

Comment: First of all it would help tremendously if you actually pasted your code.

Comment: maybe `readList` isn't being called at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is not with your list printing code - that's going to work fine, provided it is called with some data.

For reference, there's a nicer way to evaluate for effects with lists: `List.app : ('a -> unit) -> 'a list -> unit`.  It's like `List.map`, but it doesn't construct a list as a return value.  Another one you might like is `String.concatWith`, which often makes printing code easier, e.g.:

```
print (String.concatWith "\n" (map xx lst))
```

And as a final note, you've used lots of unnecessary parentheses there in your example code.  You rarely need to parenthesise expressions - especially not if there is no function application involves (i.e., writing `(lst)` or `(xx)` is always just going to mean `lst` or `xx`, and does not resolve any ambiguity (because there is none).  Similarly in your patterns, they could just as easily be written `(IntToken a)` without changing the meaning (and possibly adding to readability).

Comment: what do you mean? i provide data for the function, otherwise i wouldn't get output.     -- the parentheses thing is for me, i understand the code better like that, because i come from java\C. :)

Comment: The function you are calling is called `Reader.stringToSexpr`, not `readList`.  I can't see where `readList` is actually being called.

Comment: it's a big programm (that's why not all the code appeares). i'm writing a compiler as homework for studies. but it gets there. thats sure.

Comment: The fact that your `print "x"` example failed suggests otherwise.  There's no way that should not have printed *something* if the function was indeed being called with a non-empty list, unless of course you've inadvertently eclipsed the `print` function with something else.  You could try calling `TextIO.print` instead to make sure that's not the case.

Comment: I've already rewritten more or less every thing in the Reader, and already submitted the homework. Now there's no way to know, but I guess you were right, so I'm accepting the answer. Thanks